# Obscure 4-way shower faucet cartridge

Tags: plumbing, faucet, plumbing-fixture, diverter

Where can I get a 4-way shower faucet cartridge? I need one that's 42mm, and Amazon only has 40 or 45mm.
[image]

Comment: Do you know what brand the faucet is?

Answer (score 2):

Cartridges (and most every other part...) for shower valves are *specific to brand and model*. You can't just go looking for a part the way you are thinking you can. It has to be designed to fit **your** valve exactly. You need to hunt by brand and model...

Comment: It's a no-brand, something from China...I know the picture is the correct "brand" but they don't have the size I need.

Comment: They're on that Alibaba site from China where you order like 100,000 of each and distribute, but I only need one.

Comment: You should prepare to open the wall and change the entire shower valve. This time replace it with a reputable brand with a market presence in your area and widespread parts distribution; in U.S. I would recommend Moen, Delta, Price Pfister, American Standard, Kohler... and not much else.